# Help with PyEPL logging

Tags: python, file, logging, concatenation

I have never used Python before, most of my programming has been in MATLAB and Unix. However, recently I have been given a new assignment that involves fixing an old PyEPL program written by a former employee (I've tried contacting him directly but he won't respond to my e-mails). I know essentially nothing about Python, and though I am picking it up, I thought I'd just quickly ask for some advice here.

Anyway, there are two issues at hand here, really. The first is this segment of the code:

```
exp = Experiment()
exp.setBreak()
vt = VideoTrack("video")
at = AudioTrack("audio")
kt = KeyTrack("key")
log = LogTrack("session")
clk = PresentationClock()
```

I understand what this is doing; it is creating a series of tracking files in the directory after the program is run. However, I have searched a bunch of online tutorials and can't find a reference to any of these commands in them. Maybe I'm not searching the right places or something, but I cannot find ANYTHING about this.

What I need to do is modify the

```
log = LogTrack("session")
```

segment of the code, so that all of the session.log files go into a new directory, separate from the other log files. But I also need to find a way to not only concatenate them into a single session.log file, but add a new column to that file that will add the subject number (the program is meant to be run by multiple subjects to collect data).

I am not asking anyone to do my work for me, but if anyone could give me some pointers, or any sort of advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check if there is a line in the code

```
from some_module_name import *
```

This could easily explain why you can call these functions (classes?). It will also tell you what file to look in to modify the code for `LogTrack`.

Edit:

So, a little digging seems to find that `LogTrack` is part of PyEPL's `textlog` module. These other classes are from other modules. Somewhere in this person's code should be a line something like:

```
from PyEPL.display import VideoTrack
from PyEPL.sound import AudioTrack
from PyEPL.textlog import LogTrack
...
```

This means that these are classes specific to PyEPL. There are a few ways you could go about modifying how they work. You can modify the source of the `LogTrack` class so that it operates differently. Perhaps easier would be to simply subclass `LogTrack` and change some of its methods.

Either of these will require a fairly thorough understanding of how this class operates.

In any case, I would download the source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyepl/files/pyepl/1.0.29/), open up the code/textlog.py file, and start reading how LogTrack works.